# how function.apply works in javascript

Tags: javascript, apply

I'm just trying out `function.apply()` in javascript, I'm having trouble understanding how it parses the array parameter we pass in. For example,

```
var update = function(name, profession){
    this.name = name;
    this.profession = profession;
}

var p1 = {
    name : "bond", 
    profession : "actor"
}

console.log(p1.name, p1.profession);  //outputs bond actor
```

Now lets change p1's properties using apply() method

```
update.apply(p1, ["john", "developer"]);
```

1st argument is value for `this` pointer, and 2nd argument is an `array`

```
console.log(p1.name, p1.profession);  //outputs john developer
```

The function `update()` takes in two parameters name and profession, but I'm only passing in one `array` parameter  `["john", "developer"]` to it through `apply()` method. I do not understand how my `update()` method is correctly capturing the properties from the array that is passed in and updating each property accordingly.

Thank you!

Comment: Its works similar to ES6 [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator. The first argument is your context or `this` as you said in its entirety. The second array will be expanded so that each argument in the array becomes a separate function parameter when the function is called.

Comment: Why would it matter *how* `apply` does that? It's exactly what `apply` was meant to do, and you seem to know that it does it, so what's the problem?

Comment: @Bergi Judging by the example code i think there is confusion that the OP thinks the two are linked in some way. They are passing in context and arguments with apply, but then in the `update` method setting the context properties as though it was some form of constructor. Both approaches are not needed at the same time. They have the same affect either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) works by spreading out the array and passing each element of that array as a different parameter. This is all determined by the order in which they appear in the array.

Example:

```js
function printThings(pre, a, b, c) {
  var el = document.querySelector('pre'); // Put the text into an element
  el.innerHTML += pre + '> 1: ' + a + '\n';
  el.innerHTML += pre + '> 2: ' + b + '\n';
  el.innerHTML += pre + '> 3: ' + c + '\n\n';
}

// Calling it normally
printThings('Normal', 'A', 'B', 'C');

// Call using apply
// Notice how the array is in the same order as when we called it normally
printThings.apply(null, ['Apply (1)', 'A', 'B', 'C']);

// Now we'll rearrange the arguments
printThings.apply(null, ['Apply (2)', 'C', 'A', 'B']);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

It's also worth mentioning the first argument passed to `apply`. In the previous examples, I was passing in `null` since I'm not using `this` inside of the function at all. But what if I was? Then I can set `this` to the value passed as the first argument.

```js
function printThings(pre) {
  var el = document.querySelector('pre');
  // Here, we expect "this" to be an object with a, b, and c properties
  el.innerHTML += pre + '> A: ' + this.a + '\n';
  el.innerHTML += pre + '> B: ' + this.b + '\n';
  el.innerHTML += pre + '> C: ' + this.c + '\n\n';
}

// Passing in null defaults to using the global context
printThings.apply(null, ['Global']);

// Notice how they're all undefined since there are no a, b, or c properties on the global scope

// But now we'll pass it an object with some values
printThings.apply({
  a: 'A',
  b: 'B',
  c: 'C'
}, ['Matching Values']);

// And just to drill the point home, here's an object with the right properties but different values
printThings.apply({
  a: 'Here',
  b: 'We',
  c: 'Go'
}, ['Different']);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

The exact nitty-gritty details of *how* it works depends on the JS engine you're running it in.